# Notification won't dismiss when swiped android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications

My notification should dismiss when swiped as it is not ongoing, however it does not and only does when you click it. Here is the notification code:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ArticleView.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(NOTIFY_MESSAGE, articles[0]);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ArticleView.class);
  /* Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack */
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    Notification mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.new_blog_post))
            .setContentText(articles[0][0])
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.new_blog_post))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(articles[0][0] + "\n" + articles[0][1] + "\n" + articles[0][2]))
            .setPriority((Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(0xff00ff00, 300, 300)
            .setSound(Uri.parse(SettingsActivity.getRingtone(this)))
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .build();
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    mBuilder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    if (SettingsActivity.getVibrate(this))
        mBuilder.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing these lines:

```
if (SettingsActivity.getVibrate(this))
    mBuilder.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE == 2 == Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT

(see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_VIBRATE)

Comment: How would I make it vibrate then?

Comment: I think you want to do:
    mBuild.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;